# Revert string to initial casing and punctuation_pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, duplicates

Is there a way I can modify this code to keep its logic but revert the strings to initial casing and punctuation?

```
data = {'duplicate_column':["Adidas Women's Womens A004 Snow Boot", 'Amul Milk, 100ml, 100ML', 'L-OCCITANE L´Occitane CREMA MANI', 'Corneto Ice Cream Ice, 300 ml -300ml', 'Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori,set']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
punct = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{}~´'
transtab = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(punct, ''))

df['new_column'] = [
' '.join(dict.fromkeys(s.translate(transtab).lower().split()))
for s in df['duplicate']
```

This code is removing duplicates from column 'duplicate' and creates a new column with the result. Would need to revert the strings to initial casing and punctuation.

Duplicate column(initial data):

```
Adidas Women's Womens A004 Snow Boot
Amul Milk, 100ml, 100ML
L-OCCITANE L´Occitane CREMA MANI
Corneto Ice Cream Ice, 300 ml -300ml
Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori,set
```

New column created with the code above:

```
adidas womens a004 snow boot
amul milk 100ml
loccitane crema mani
corneto ice cream 300 ml 300ml
béaba set di 6 contenitori set
```

Desired output:

```
Adidas Women's A004 Snow Boot
Amul Milk, 100ml
L-OCCITANE CREMA MANI
Corneto Ice Cream, 300 ml
Béaba, Set di 6 Contenitori
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than fixing the output to restore. punctuation/case don't drop it in the first place. You could use a custom function based on sets:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(punct))
def remove_dup(s):
    seen = set()
    keep = []
    for w in s.split():
        w2 = regex.sub('', w.lower())
        if w2 in seen:
            continue 
        seen.add(w2)
        keep.append(w)
    return ' '.join(keep).strip(punct)
        
df['new_column'] = list(map(remove_dup, df['duplicate_column']))
```

Output:

```
                        duplicate_column                       new_column
0   Adidas Women's Womens A004 Snow Boot    Adidas Women's A004 Snow Boot
1                Amul Milk, 100ml, 100ML                 Amul Milk, 100ml
2       L-OCCITANE L´Occitane CREMA MANI            L-OCCITANE CREMA MANI
3   Corneto Ice Cream Ice, 300 ml -300ml  Corneto Ice Cream 300 ml -300ml
4  Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori,set   Béaba Set di 6 Contenitori,set
```

###### alternative

```
import re
pat = '[\s%s]' % re.escape(punct)
regex = re.compile(pat)
regex2 = re.compile(fr'({pat}+)(?!s\b|\s*ml\b)')

def remove_dup(s):
    seen = set()
    keep = []
    for w in regex2.split(s):
        if len(w)>1:
            w2 = regex.sub('', w.lower())
            if w2 in seen:
                continue 
            seen.add(w2)
            keep.append(w.strip())
        else:
            keep.append(w)
    return ''.join(keep).strip(punct)
        
df['new_column'] = list(map(remove_dup, df['duplicate_column']))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                        duplicate_column                      new_column
0   Adidas Women's Womens A004 Snow Boot  Adidas Women's  A004 Snow Boot
1                Amul Milk, 100ml, 100ML                 Amul Milk,100ml
2       L-OCCITANE L´Occitane CREMA MANI        L-OCCITANE L´ CREMA MANI
3   Corneto Ice Cream Ice, 300 ml -300ml       Corneto Ice Cream ,300 ml
4  Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori,set     Béaba ,Set di 6 Contenitori
```

Comment: thank you so much but this will not cover the last two rows for example, it will still result in duplicates because of punctuation. Is there a way to cover that as well?

Comment: Yes if you accept to lose the punctuation, just split on the spaces+punctuation.

Comment: unfortunately, i have to keep it but that is creating issues

Comment: But even then it's tricky as "women's" and "womens" wouldn't match

Comment: can we reduce/have an exception for commas and minus signs only?

Comment: Alternative, still not exactly what you want but removes more cases

Comment: this second output looks great but what is the change in the code, for me is not working as is the same code

Comment: can you share please the code you've used for the alternative version? It is actually returning the expected output but you may have pasted the same code. Can you please double check on that? Many thanks

Comment: @Isa I had posted the wrong block ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

```py
import re

remove_punct = re.compile("""[!"#$%&'()*+-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{}~´]""")
millilitres = re.compile(r"(\d+)\s+(ml)", flags=re.I)


def remove_duplicates(x):
    # do some basic preprocess
    x = x.replace(",", " ")
    x = millilitres.sub(r"\1\2", x)

    words = x.split()
    words_without_punct = remove_punct.sub("", x).lower().split()
    dupl, out = set(), []
    for w, wwp in zip(words, words_without_punct):
        if wwp not in dupl:
            out.append(w)
            dupl.add(wwp)
    return " ".join(out)


df["new_column"] = df["duplicate_column"].apply(remove_duplicates)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                        duplicate_column                     new_column
0   Adidas Women's Womens A004 Snow Boot  Adidas Women's A004 Snow Boot
1                Amul Milk, 100ml, 100ML                Amul Milk 100ml
2       L-OCCITANE L´Occitane CREMA MANI          L-OCCITANE CREMA MANI
3   Corneto Ice Cream Ice, 300 ml -300ml        Corneto Ice Cream 300ml
4  Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori,set     Béaba Set di 6 Contenitori
```